# xfce4 - 'Run Program' dialogue box does not appear when double clicking script

Tags: scripts, xfce

Ubuntu 12.04 > Xfce4

On my previous Ubuntu distro, when I double clicked scripts I got a little dialogue window that asked me if I wanted to run the script as a program or run it in terminal.  Similar to this window:

[image]

Since upgrading, I have never seen that window.  I have ensured that the option to 'Allow executing as a program is enabled' and the script works if I run it through terminal.  I simply just don't get the prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've never seen that prompt on Xubuntu 12.04, nor Xubuntu 12.10. Do you have Ubuntu + Xfce, or Xubuntu? Xubuntu =/= Ubuntu + Xfce. In fact, the prompt in the image does not even look like Xubuntu's or Xfce's default appearance.

Comment: @ignis -- No, I'm sure this window is from Gnome or some of the other windows managers.  I became familiar with the Window while running default installations of Ubuntu.
I have recently switched to 12.04 and Xfce4 and now I don't see the window.   Are you indicating that this window simply does not exist in xfce4?